# Removing text nodes and check for alternative text nodes in html : Jsoup

Tags: java, javascript, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse a html string using jsoup:

```html
<div class="test">
  <br>From: <b class="sendername">Divya</b> 
  <span dir="ltr">&lt;<a href="mailto:divya@abc.net" target="_blank">divya@abc.net</a>&gt;</span>
  <br>Date: Wed, May 27, 2015 at 11:10 AM
  <br>Subject: Plan for the day 27/05/2015
  <br>To: Abhishek&lt;<a href="mailto:abhishek.sharma@abc.com" target="_blank">abhishek.sharma@abc.<wbr>com</a>&gt;, 
    <a href="mailto:xyz@abc.com" target="_blank">xyz@abc.com</a>&gt;
  <br>Cc: Ram &lt;<a href="mailto:Ram@abc.net" target="_blank">Ram@abc.net</a>&gt;
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div dir="ltr">Hi,</div>
 </div>
```

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( mailBody.getBodyHtml().get( 0 ) );
Elements elem = doc.getElementsByClass( "test" );
int totalElements = 0;
Elements childElements = elem.get( 0 ).;
int brCount = 0;
for( Element childElement : childElements )
{
    totalElements++;
    if( childElement.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase( "br" ) )
    {
        brCount++;
        if( brCount == 3 )
            break;
    }
    else
    brCount = 0;
}
for( int i = 1; i <= totalElements; i++ )
{
    childElements.get( i ).remove();
}
```

I want to get rid of all content before three consecutive br tags and there should be no text node between them.
i.e. In above case, It will remove all tags(html tags and textnode) and output will be as follows:

```html
<div class="test">
  <div dir="ltr">Hi,</div>
 </div>
```

1. How to check if there is a text node between two br tags?
2. Above code is just removing html tags, but text nodes are not getting deleted. How can I remove that?

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the html seems to be constant. So you can try the following CSS selector:

```
div.test br + br + br + div
```

#### DEMO

http://try.jsoup.org/~DiBi9Q_Ye88gi6Hq29Z44ar6xus

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String html = "<div class=\"test\">\n  <br>From: <b class=\"sendername\">Divya</b> \n  <span dir=\"ltr\">&lt;<a href=\"mailto:divya@abc.net\" target=\"_blank\">divya@abc.net</a>&gt;</span>\n  <br>Date: Wed, May 27, 2015 at 11:10 AM\n  <br>Subject: Plan for the day 27/05/2015\n  <br>To: Abhishek&lt;<a href=\"mailto:abhishek.sharma@abc.com\" target=\"_blank\">abhishek.sharma@abc.<wbr>com</a>&gt;, \n    <a href=\"mailto:xyz@abc.com\" target=\"_blank\">xyz@abc.com</a>&gt;\n  <br>Cc: Ram &lt;<a href=\"mailto:Ram@abc.net\" target=\"_blank\">Ram@abc.net</a>&gt;\n  <br>\n  <br>\n  <br>\n  <div dir=\"ltr\">Hi,</div>\n </div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element mailBody = doc.select("div.test br + br + br + div").first();
if (mailBody == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate mail body.");
}
System.out.println("** BEFORE:\n" + doc);

Document tmp = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("<div class='test'>" + mailBody.outerHtml() + "</div>");
mailBody.parent().replaceWith(tmp.select("div.test").first());
System.out.println("\n** AFTER:\n" + doc);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
** BEFORE:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="test"> 
   <br>From: 
   <b class="sendername">Divya</b> 
   <span dir="ltr">&lt;<a href="mailto:divya@abc.net" target="_blank">divya@abc.net</a>&gt;</span> 
   <br>Date: Wed, May 27, 2015 at 11:10 AM 
   <br>Subject: Plan for the day 27/05/2015 
   <br>To: Abhishek&lt;
   <a href="mailto:abhishek.sharma@abc.com" target="_blank">abhishek.sharma@abc.<wbr>com</a>&gt;, 
   <a href="mailto:xyz@abc.com" target="_blank">xyz@abc.com</a>&gt; 
   <br>Cc: Ram &lt;
   <a href="mailto:Ram@abc.net" target="_blank">Ram@abc.net</a>&gt; 
   <br> 
   <br> 
   <br> 
   <div dir="ltr">
    Hi,
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

** AFTER:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="test">
   <div dir="ltr">
     Hi, 
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```